# A Geiger counter beeps according to a Poisson arrival process, with rate 1 beep per minute.

Tags: probability, poisson-process

A Geiger counter beeps according to a Poisson arrival process, with rate 1 beep per minute. Let T_3 be the time in minutes from when the Geiger counter is turned on until the third beep.

Find P( 1 < T_3  < 3 ) = probability T_3 falls in interval (1,3).

Can someone check which of my answers are correct?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The second one is wrong since the CDF is not $1-e^{-t}.$ $T_3$ is gamma-distributed, not exponential.

Comment: P(2<T3<3) not P(1<T3<3)

Comment: @Dohleman Huh??

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, oh yeah, that makes sense. But, I can still use the Poisson distribution for this kind of question, right? So, is the first one correct?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, Maximum 3 minutes where it beeps after just under a minute, minimum 3 where it beeps right after turning on.
EDIT: wait nevermind I'm wrong

Comment: Poisson distribution is fine.

Comment: @ibuntu yes, the first solution looks right

Comment: Thanks guys :) Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you seek the probability that the third beep occurs after one minute but not after three minutes, then your first method is correct. $$\mathsf P(1< T_3\leqslant 3)~{=\mathsf P(1<T_3)-\mathsf P(3<T_3) \\= \mathsf P(N_{[0;1)}\leq 2)-\mathsf P(N_{[0;3)}\leq 2)\\=(1+1+\tfrac 12)\mathsf e^{-1}+(1+3+\tfrac 92)\mathsf e^{-3}\\=\tfrac12(5\mathsf e^{-1}+17\mathsf e^{-3})}$$